# How to set cursor to thin in insert mode, while still being block in nomal mode

Tags: vim, conemu

I have tried a lot of things from all over Stack Overflow, and I guess it's something related to conemu, I am using conemu. It's so pain to see spot every second while I'm in normal or insert mode.

I found this link but don't know which command to exactly use in my case - https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Change_cursor_shape_in_different_modes
I tried changing setting in ~/.vimrc but it never works.

I am using vim - VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Jun  1 2020 06:42:35) and I am using conEmu.

Comment: Sometimes is your terminal who does not allow this setting.

Comment: Not what you were asking, but the solution is that you should *always* be in normal mode, except for very short amounts of time where you are actually typing something. There should be no question whether you are in normal mode or insert mode, when in doubt press Escape and go back to normal mode.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I totally agree. Nerveless, it does look more natural with the changing cursor.

Comment: I guess its true, that some terminal just don't have this ability and conEmu is the only good